# Preloading and prerendering an image in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have 3 separate background images in 3 separate divs. I have a page set up to auto-scroll from one div to the next when the user hits continue. I am currently having an issue where the user can see the background images loading (quickly, but still...) I want a smooth user experience and am trying to let the images preload before the user starts playing with the app. Once I have cycled through all 3 pages everything runs smoothly. How do I have the browser load all that into memory beforehand and why is it not already doing that? Only the first div is visible to the user on page load but only because the others are hidden under overflow. I tried javascript `new Image().src = URL` but that didn't help. I tried HTML/CSS `<link rel="preload" href="./assets/img/inputs.jpg" as="image">` and that didn't help either. This is a head-scratcher for me... Any suggestions? I plan on adding a loading screen to the web app but I want to put an elegant solution behind that loading screen.

Thanks!
Brett

Comment: How big is the size of the image in terms of bytes 'cause that should be considered'

Comment: Smallest is 1.3 MG biggest is 8.5MB

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following (setting style to `display:none`) should work in most cases, assuming that *parent container not hidden*. It doesn't necessarily have to be container is which it is ultimately displayed:

```
   <img src="/assets/img/inputs.jpg" style="display: none;" />
```

Alternatively, you can try setting the height and width of the img’s to 1px each.

Comment: You’re right - this was clerical oversight as I was attempting to grab src. I have corrected.